# I have a website and it also has an application. I want to download that application from the website. How to do it?

Tags: android, web

I have a website and it also has an application. I want to download that application from the website. How to do it?

How to connect Android application that link in provided in website. How to download Android application from Website

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you application is uploaded to any android store, just put link in your website to transfer the visitors to the store to download the app by using

or if you don't uploaded it to any store :

- Upload the application APK file to your web Server:

  ```
   Use an FTP client or your web hosting control panel's file manager
   to upload the APK file to a directory on your web server.
  ```
- Create a Download Link on Your Website

  ```
   Add an HTML link to the APK file on your webpage.
  ```

```html
    <a href="/downloads/yourapp.apk" download>Download Our App</a>
```